# block domain from .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

i want to block some domain with this example script:

**.htaccess** file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http?://([^.]+\.)*google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php** file

```
<?php
// set location
$address = "Brooklyn+NY+USA";

//set map api url
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address";

//call api
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($json);
$lat = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
echo "Latitude: " . $lat . ", Longitude: " . $lng;

?>
```

result : Latitude: 40.6781784, Longitude: -73.9441579

Q: how to block data from this domain http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address= use .htaccess ?

i mean if the domain was blocked result must blank. but i still can't to solve it..

Comment: To get reasonable answers, you probably should provide more details of what you are trying to achieve. For example, you are talking of "block some domain" or "block data from this domain", but in your example `.htaccess`, you have a `RewriteCond` based on the *REFERER*. I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: .htaccess is used by the web server in determining how it deals with requests. It doesn’t come into play in your situation. If you want to block the application making outgoing web requests you’ll have to do that some other way, perhaps changing the /etc/hosts file so that maps.google.com isn’t correctly resolved or simply removing the requesting code from the php file.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*google\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

> **OR If You Want To Denying access from a any specific domain.com, do this**

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "domain.com" bad_referer
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from ALL
Deny from env=bad_referer
```

This will show an Denying access if any one try to access www.domain.com. and if user clicks on a link at domain.com then its redirects to your site, they then see a error `403 Forbidden`

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.google.com/
RewriteRule /* http://www.anydomain.com [R,L]
```

Using This You can redirect any user to from `www.google.com` to `anydomain.com`

---

### Updated

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} maps.google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?maps.google\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)    - [F]
```

Comment: that same with my set

Comment: @Andriyansyahabdulmaaz hmm can you add maps.google.com

Comment: i have following your Answer but it's still showing, **result : Latitude: 40.6781784, Longitude: -73.9441579**

Comment: its posible to block some domain in php script use .htaccess?

Comment: @Andriyansyahabdulmaaz wait i will check

Comment: how to block outgoing data from some domain like my qustions?

Comment: @Andriyansyahabdulmaaz Check The Updatec part of my Question

Comment: Still not working.. any sugestion? ip blocker also cant solf it. :(